# Dynamic Panel Content from function call

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jpanel

What I am trying to do is add two X by 2 grid panels in the first row of a 2x2 grid content panel, leaving the bottom row of the content panel blank.

To populate the cells on the top row I want to use a function which uses a loop to generate a text field and a slider. the text field calling it's input from `textList[n]`.

So this breaks down into two primary questions.

If I have a function:

```
public static void makeTop(String textName) {
    JTextField textBox = new JTextField(textName);
    textBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    textBox.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    textBox.setEditable(false);

    SpinnerNumberModel numSpinner = new SpinnerNumberModel(10,0,100,1);
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(numSpinner);
    spinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
}
```

And a frame w/ panel:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel cPane = new JPanel((new GridLayout(2,2)));

    frame.add(cPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

How could I add the text field and spinner created in `makeTop` to `cPane`?

`cPane.add()` doesn't like function calls, and making `cPane` public didn't seem to help when trying to add the content in `makeTop()`.

Secondly, let's say `makeTop` is called as follows, with `N` being arbitrary and `textList[]` being populated with Strings:

```
for(i=N;i>0;i--){
    makeTop(textList[i]);
}
```

How could I get the text fields and sliders to be unique instances when creating them in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

> `cPane.add` doesn't like function calls, and making `cPane` public didn't
>   seem to help when trying to add the content in `makeTop()`

It won't work, indeed, because by contract `makeTop(String textName)` is returning `void`. But if you make this change:

```
public static JPanel makeTop(String textName){

    JTextField textBox = new JTextField(textName);
    textBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    textBox.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    textBox.setEditable(false);

    SpinnerNumberModel numSpinner = new SpinnerNumberModel(10,0,100,1);
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(numSpinner);
    spinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(textBox);
    panel.add(spinner);

    return panel;
}
```

Then `cPane.add(makeTop("Whatever"));` will work like a charm.

Comment: much appreciated. that little bit is going to go a long way. still getting adjusted to code. return types. noted.

Comment: upon tinkering: this solved everything. thanks again.

Comment: @user2903422 you're welcome! :-) if this worked for you don't forget accept the answer. Take a look to [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)